# Task.WhenAny does not exist when task is finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, static

We have a logic for a background job to keep running, either every 20 minuts, or when a task if finished.

A simplified version of what I want to do is as followed:

Task to control if we need to exit:

```
private static TaskCompletionSource<bool> forceSyncTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
```

Background job:

```
     Task.Factory.StartNew(
                async () =>
                {
                    do
                    {
                        await Dosomething();
                        await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)), forceSyncTask.Task);

                        // Always reset the force sync property
                        forceSyncTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                    }
                    while (true);
                });
```

Then everytime there is a notification comes, I run the following to force to exit the Task.WhenAny

```
    if (!forceSyncTask.Task.IsCompleted)
    {
        forceSyncTask.TrySetResult(true);
    }
```

I tested it in dev box and it works. However after I deployed it to our webervice in prod environment, 
even if I successfully SetResult (I have logging to know if TrySetResult returns true or not), the Task.WhenAny does not exit as expected.

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: There is probably a race condition regarding the `forceSyncTask` field, which is accessed by multiple threads without synchronization. As a side note, if your intention is to run a job exactly every 20 min, you should create the `Task.Delay` task before awaiting the `Dosomething`, and `await` it afterwards.

Comment: Your condition is `if (forceSyncTask.Task.IsCompleted)`. Shouldn't it be the opposite? `if (!forceSyncTask.Task.IsCompleted)`, otherwise you're completing the task only if it's already completed. And in any case, `TrySetResult` implements this check internally, so you can remove the whole condition

Comment: Sorry I'll update that part.   In prod it is the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you use an established solution for pausing asynchronous methods, such as [Stephen Toub's `PauseToken`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/) or the [`PauseToken` from my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/5ede2ebad24bb3696fd730de2d7e11cda92bf8dc/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/PauseToken.cs). There's some red flags in the code as it currently stands: [`StartNew` with an `async` delegate and without a `TaskScheduler`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), and `TaskCompletionSource<T>` being used without the `RunContinuationsAsynchronously` option. It's better to stick to higher-level constructs (`Task.Run` and `PauseToken`, respectively) because there are lots of sharp corners on the low-level constructs.

As far as what exactly the problem is, that's difficult to tell, especially since you (and we) cannot reproduce it locally. Here's my top guesses:

1. You're running into a problem caused by the fact that [continuations run synchronously if possible](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) - i.e., `TrySetResult` ends up directly invoking some code within `Task.WhenAny`.
2. You're experiencing thread exhaustion on your production server.